# Error with freeing memory in C, visual studio

Tags: c, free

I am working on a project that I have made use of Calloc and I am trying to free the memory at the end of my main{} function. However, after the program finishes running and I click on the stop, I get this "proj.exe has triggered a breakpoint."
at this set of codes:

`while (freeSpace != NULL) {
        free(freeSpace++);
    }`

Here are my codes for allocating memory:

```
scanf("%d", &SEG);
  BLOCKS = 128 / SEG;

for (int k = 0; k < BLOCKS; k++)
{
    memory = (int *)calloc(BLOCKS, sizeof(int));
    // handle memory allocation failure

}


for (int i = 0; i < BLOCKS; i++)
{

    memory[i] = (int *)calloc(SEG, sizeof(int));
    // handle memory allocation failure

}

for (int l = 0; l < BLOCKS+5; l++)
{
    //freeSpace = (int*)malloc(l * sizeof(int));
    freeSpace = (int *)calloc( BLOCKS + 5, sizeof(int));
    // handle memory allocation failure

}


for (int o = 0; o < BLOCKS; o++)
{
    memorySpace = (int *)calloc(BLOCKS, sizeof(int));
    // handle memory allocation failure

}
```

`

This is the part where I free my memory:

`while (freeSpace != NULL) {
        free(freeSpace++);
    }`

Can someone please assist me?

Comment: The `memory` seems like an array of address pointer?

Comment: How are each of the variables you're using declared?

Answer (score 2):

Its really hard to fix your issue because it seems like that these are only a part of your code or it is a prototype?
The following code only based on some 'guess':

```
int main()
{
scanf("%d", &SEG);
BLOCKS = 128 / SEG;

int* memory = (int *)calloc(BLOCKS+1, sizeof(int*));    // the last is a 'NULL' pointer
memset(memory, 0, sizeof(int*)*BLOCKS+1);

for (int i = 0; i < BLOCKS; i++)
{
    memory[i] = (int *)calloc(SEG, sizeof(int));
    // handle memory allocation failure

}

while (memory != NULL) {
        free(memory++);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding how pointers work when allocating arrays. Your very first loop has a memory leak in it because you are changing what I am assuming the "memory" pointer is pointing to.

To allocate an array in C would be like below.

`int *bigspace;
 bigspace = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));`

Here we made the pointer "bigspace" point to a new chunk of memory 20 times the size of an integer which is an array. If you did something like below..

`int *bigspace;
 bigspace = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
 bigspace = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));`

This would be no bueno. We are first making "bigspace" pointer point to a chunk of memory (array of ints) and then we are changing what "bigspace" is pointing to by making it point to a new chunk of memory. This means your first chunk of memory does not have a pointer to it anymore and that memory is leaked!

Comment: malloc in this case is the same as calloc except calloc initializes the elements in the array to be zero and malloc would be random garbage numbers to start with. More info on allocating memory here.https://pebble.gitbooks.io/learning-c-with-pebble/content/chapter08.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the value of freeSpace++ is garbage at the end of your allocated memory. 
Free a garbage pointer causes the problem.